# Printing zero in while loop

Tags: c++, c

I want to apply a while loop and have written that `while (a!=-1)`; it should exit but it's printing "0" always and I don't know why.  Can you explain?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long num;   
    int a,i,j;
    int arr[10000];
    float x;
    while( a != -1)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a);
        int sum=0;

        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
            sum = sum + arr[i];
        }
        x = sum%a;

        if (x == 0)
        {
            int z = sum/a;
            int y=0;
            for(j=0;j<a;j++)
            {
                if (arr[j]>z)
                {
                    y = (arr[j] - z) + y ;
                }
            }
            printf("%d",y);
        }
        else
            printf("-1");

    }

}
```

I think it is printing `y`; how to avoid so that it only exits?

Comment: Can you come up with a minimal example that shows the problem behavior? There's a lot going on here, and since you used single letter variables it's hard to determine even what this procedure should be doing.

Comment: Why printf("-1")? Why not just print("-1")?

Comment: I notice you haven't initialized `a` before entering the `while` loop.

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: Sorry my mistake , actually the printf statement of y is the key , when i remove that like than it exits but if that statement is there than it prints 0

Comment: You should really pay attention to your compiler warnings. Any compiler worth using would complain about `int a; while (a != -1);`. If yours doesn't, __turn up the warnings__. For `gcc`, `-Wall -Wextra` are nice, and `-Werror` will make sure you never overlook any warnings. (Though some warnings _can_ be ignored, so many developers don't care for `-Werror`.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got my answer actually i have to take my `scanf("%d",&a);` outside while loop ;

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you failed to initialize `a` before running the while loop, so the behavior of your program will be undefined and it could just terminate right away.

Second, you said "while(a!=0)" in your question but your code says "while(a != -1)".  Which one is correct: 0 or -1?  Maybe if you just changed the -1 to a 0 the program would behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write `while( a != 0)` but you actually have written `while( a != -1)`.

Fix that. Then the loop will exit when you enter `0`.